# Azure Table Storage separate thread for ExecuteSegmentedQuery and StreamWriter

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a console application which retrieves data from an Azure Table Storage and transfers it to a text file. Currently, my code look like this:

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            //header
            writer.Write("PartitionKey|RowKey|Timestamp|Id|");
            writer.WriteLine();

            do
            {
                var entities = new List<TModel>();
                var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<TModel>(), token);
                entities.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
                count = count + 1000;

                Console.WriteLine("{0} records retrieved", count);

                //records
                foreach (TModel entity in entities)
                {
                    writer.Write("\"" + entity.PartitionKey + "\"|\"" + entity.RowKey + "\"|" + entity.Timestamp + "|" + entity.Id);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
                token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
            }
            while (token != null);
            writer.Dispose();
```

Now this code runs in a single-thread which means it will get the first 1000 records before writing it to the text file, then will get the next 1000 records then append it to a file.

I am wondering if there is a way to split the processing of the data retrieval and the writing to file into two separate threads which means one thread will just perform the execution of the segmented query and one will perform the writing of the data to file (like a queue)?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I suggest you create 2 threads. One is producer thread and the other is consumer thread. In addition, a thread safe collection is required. We could use ConcurrentQueue Class to store the entities which will be accessed from these 2 threads.

Code below is for your reference.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Run producer  thread
        Task.Run(new Action(ReadDataFromTable));
        //Run consumer  thread
        Task.Run(new Action(WriteDataToText));

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static ConcurrentQueue<TModel> entitiesQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<TModel>();
    //This tag point out whether the read process is down
    public static bool ReadTableFinished = false;
    public static void ReadDataFromTable()
    {
        do
        {
            var entities = new List<TModel>();
            var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<TModel>(), token);
            entities.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
            count = count + 1000;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} records retrieved", count);

            //Save entites to the queue
            foreach (TModel entity in entities)
            {
                entitiesQueue.Enqueue(entity);
            }
            token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
        }
        while (token != null);

        ReadTableFinished = true;
    }

    public static void WriteDataToText()
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            //header
            writer.Write("PartitionKey|RowKey|Timestamp|Id|");
            writer.WriteLine();

            do
            {
                TModel entity = null;
                //Read and remove entity from queue 
                entitiesQueue.TryDequeue(out entity);

                if (entity != null)
                {
                    //Write data to text file
                    writer.Write("\"" + entity.PartitionKey + "\"|\"" + entity.RowKey + "\"|" + entity.Timestamp + "|" + entity.Id);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    //If all the entities are read out from the table and now there is no entities in the queue, we will break this loop and exit current thread.
                    if (ReadTableFinished)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (true);
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

> adding a breakpoint will not enter the code without Console.Read().

If you don't add Console.Read() to block the UI thread, the UI thread will run completely. Other threads(tasks) can't be run if the state of UI thread is completed. If you don't want to add Console.Read(). You could use following code in Main method instead. **Task.WaitAll method will block current UI thread until all the tasks are run completely.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Run producer  thread
    Task t1 = Task.Run(new Action(ReadDataFromTable));
    //Run consumer  thread
    Task t2 = Task.Run(new Action(WriteDataToText));

    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
    Console.WriteLine("all completed");
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I run this code. No messages in the console and the text file does not appear. Maybe you need to add something in the Main section so that the threads will run.

Comment: Task.Run method will invoke a new thread immediately. Did you remove Console.Read();? If yes, please re-add it.  In addition, you could add a breakpoint to your code and run your code line by line to check whether they are executed as expected.

Comment: I intend the console application to be an unattended service therefore adding Console.Read() would mean requiring a user input which I think doesn't make sense for an unattended service. Also, adding a breakpoint will not enter the code without Console.Read(). What can be other options aside from Console.Read()?